# How to convert XML to a custom object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

XML File below.  Looking to be able to read from and write to the below file.

Using the below code I am able to SEARCH for a specific pagename node

```
`XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(path); 
 metadata m = new metadata();
 XElement emp = xmldoc.Descendants("data").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Element("pagename").Value == pagename);

        if (emp != null)
        {
           //How to populate each child node
           // dctermscreator.en = this
           // dctermscreator.fr = this

           //so on
        }`

 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <root>
 <data>
  <pagename>default</pagename>
  <metadata>
    <desc>
      <en>eng desc</en>
      <fr>desc fra</fr>
    </desc>
    <dctermscreator>
      <en>eng desc</en>
      <fr>desc fra</fr>
    </dctermscreator>
    <dctermssubject>
      <en>eng desc</en>
      <fr>desc fra</fr>
    </dctermssubject>
  </metadata>
 </data>
 </root>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [XmlSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) is what you need just call deserialize and it will do all work for you. You can also use [CreateReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560(v=vs.110).aspx)  to get xml reader from XElement